# Implementação relacionamento n para n no Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

Talvez seja algo simples para a maioria, mas gostaria de saber como implementar na pratica um relacionamento n para n entre tabelas do Mysql utilizando Delphi.

Criei o diagrama de meu BD no MySQL Workbench, criei o DB, tudo certo. 
Minha dúvida é: as tabelas criadas automaticamente quando é feito um relacionamento n para n eu preciso criar uma rotina para salvar os dados nesta tabela na hora de cadastrar novos registros, ou é possível fazer isso automaticamente?

Complementando a postagem:

O sistema que estou fazendo é para pesquisa de satisfação. 
Terei as tabelas:
Cliente: Dados do cliente pesquisado:
Pesquisa: Cadastro da pesquisa. 
Perguntas_pesquisa: tabela n:n juntando a pesquisa com as perguntas que fazer parte da pesquisa
Perguntas: Perguntas de todas as pesquisas
Perguntas_opções _resposta: tabela n:n que junta a resposta as opções de resposta da pergunta (são todas resposta de multipla escolha para cada pergunta)
Opções_respostas: Todas as opções de resposta
Respostas: Tabela da pesquisa em si, que junta a pergunta, a opção de resposta
Resposta_cliente: Liga o cliente as respostas dadas.

Para o cadastro de perguntas e resposta, acho que tranquilo pois tenho que cadastras primeiro as perguntas e respostas, para depois ligar as duas na tabela n:n, o mesmo no cadastro de opções de resposta. 
Minha dúvida fica mesmo por conta da tabela  Respostas_cliente, pois na hora que cadastro uma nova resposta, já vou ter que registrar nesta tabela. Queria saber se tem algo automático para salvar estes dados relacionados.

No Delphi vou utilizar os componentes padrão para acesso a databases, ou mesmo o Zeos Access.
Abaixo o diagrama.

Talvez como eu não conheço muito bem desta parte de modelagem de DB, pode ser que exista uma forma mais simples de criar este sistema, mantendo a flexibilidade de criação de novas pesquisas, perguntas e opções de resposta.

[image: Diagrama]

Comment: Da uma olhada nestes links, talvez encontre algo que possa ajudar. http://www.devmedia.com.br/master-detail-simples-e-descomplicado-para-iniciantes-delphi/20370 http://www.devmedia.com.br/quick-tips-mestre-detalhe-em-delphi/15676

Comment: Olá, Conseguiu resolver teu problema?

Answer (score 1):

O delphi não faz isso de forma automática. O que você pode fazer é implementar um evento **afterpost** da vida e gravar os registros na *N to N*.

Comment: Obrigado Edgar. E tem algum sistema que faça de forma automática?

Comment: @user3771516 É possível fazer isso com Hibernate, mas não creio que tenha isso para delphi. Você teria que fazer um **webservice** em **java** ou **.net** e invoca-lo usando Delphi.